# MS EXCEL SUMIF/SUMIFS Date and Name Fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Here is the code i'm using:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,">="&$D$1-DAY($D$1)+1,B:B, ">"&(EOMONTH($D$1,0)),D:D, "SAVEDEB")
```

I'm trying to grasp exactly what's happening with this script.

Below are the columns and the info in the columns. Ultimately what i'm trying to do is say, bring me all the "Savedeb" for the Current Month by looking column B. D1 is where todays() is located.

So.. Bring me the current month savedeb amount.

```
A         B              C                 D        E
2017_01 01/12/17    Savings Transfer    SAVEDEB  $150.00 
2017_01 01/26/17    Savings             SAVEDEB  $150.00 
2017_01 01/27/17    Savings             SAVEDEB  $25.00 
2017_09 09/21/17    Savings Transfer    SAVEDEB  $150.00
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=SUMIFS(E:E, A:A, TEXT(D1, "yyyy_mm"), D:D, "SAVEDEB")
```

I think you had a `>` where you should have had a `<=` in your original formula. e.g. `B:B, "<="&EOMONTH($D$1,0)`.

Comment: Yes! You were right once I updated my formula to "<=" it worked! However, in your formula, what does or how does TEXT(D1, YYYY_MM) do?

Comment: Put `=TEXT(D1, "YYYY_MM")` into an unused cell and find out.

Comment: I see! That would be way more efficient, but it's also bringing back $0.00 as the value!

Comment: You are going to have to examine the actual data in column A to see why it doesn't match. Perhaps they are actual dates with a custom number format. Certainly not anything close to a normal date format.